I would like to know how to avoid unnecessary duplication when comparing two data in Pandas merge
import pandas
    df1 = pandas.DataFrame(
        {
            'code': ['001', '001'],
            'name': ['test1', 'test1'],
            'date': ['2024-01-01', '2024-01-01'],
            'value1': [1, 2],
            'value2': [1, 2],
            'sum': [2, 4]
        }
    )
    df2 = pandas.DataFrame(
        {
            'code': ['001', '001', '001', '002'],
            'name': ['test1', 'test1', 'test1', 'test2'],
            'date': ['2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-02-01'],
            'value1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
            'value2': [1, 2, 3, 4],
            'sum': [2, 4, 6, 8]
        }
    )
    result = pandas.merge(df1, df2, on=['code', 'name', 'date'], how='outer', indicator=True)
    print(result[['code', 'name', 'date', 'sum_x', 'sum_y', '_merge']])

When the above data is printed, it appears as shown below.
  code   name        date  sum_x  sum_y      _merge
0  001  test1  2024-01-01    2.0      2        both
1  001  test1  2024-01-01    2.0      4        both
2  001  test1  2024-01-01    2.0      6        both
3  001  test1  2024-01-01    4.0      2        both
4  001  test1  2024-01-01    4.0      4        both
5  001  test1  2024-01-01    4.0      6        both
6  002  test2  2024-02-01    NaN      8  right_only

Two data have been added to df2.
I looked into it through many methods and searches, but the closest thing I tried was to use merge to create unique values ​​and compare them.
But I couldn't create the output value I wanted.
My goal is to compare 1:1 what was created and what was lost in df1 and df2.
I kept trying to remove row values ​​that were unnecessarily created during merge, but it didn't work.
The material I want to create is as below.
  code   name        date  sum_x  sum_y      _merge
0  001  test1  2024-01-01      2      2        both
4  001  test1  2024-01-01      4      4        both
5  001  test1  2024-01-01    NaN      6        right_only
6  002  test2  2024-02-01    NaN      8        right_only

I tried to delete unnecessary rows using deduplication and qurey.
I also tried creating eigenvalues ​​and comparing them, but I couldn't create what I wanted.
I tried looking up information using Stack Overflow and gpt.

It looks like you should include the sum columns as keys, optionally renaming them before the merge:
result = pandas.merge(df1.rename(columns={'sum': 'sum_x'})
                         .drop(columns=['value1', 'value2']),
                      df2.rename(columns={'sum': 'sum_y'})
                         .drop(columns=['value1', 'value2']),
                      left_on=['code', 'name', 'date', 'sum_x'],
                      right_on=['code', 'name', 'date', 'sum_y'],
                      how='outer', indicator=True)

Output:
  code   name        date  sum_x  sum_y      _merge
0  001  test1  2024-01-01    2.0      2        both
1  001  test1  2024-01-01    4.0      4        both
2  001  test1  2024-01-01    NaN      6  right_only
3  002  test2  2024-02-01    NaN      8  right_only

